# How can I get the true horizontal rotation of the scene camera in VPython?

Tags: math, 3d, camera, rotation, vpython

I'm trying to get the horizontal rotation of the camera, but the scene.camera.axis.x seems to be completely random and makes no sense at all. I need the rotation in degrees because that's what I need to rotate my object to the camera.

Here is what ive tried:

I tried inputting the X in the sin for rotation, and Z in the cos for rotation, which didn't work.
I just tried doing only X in both sin and cos for rotation, it seemed random.

This is my code. (model is just an obj files text, but I excluded it and the function source code because those are not the problem, and would make it ridiculously long.)

```
loadobject(model,size=3)

scene.camera.autoscale = False

sine = 0
rotx = 0
roty = 0
print(offset)

scene.camera.axis = vec(0,0,0)
while True:
  rate(60)
  vertindex = 0
  rotx = scene.camera.axis.x
  
  roty += 1
  for v in verts:
    v.pos.x = (sin(radians(rotx)) * (objectposes[vertindex].z - offset.z)) + (sin(radians(rotx - 90)) * (objectposes[vertindex].x - offset.x))
    v.pos.z = (cos(radians(rotx)) * (objectposes[vertindex].z - offset.z)) + (cos(radians(rotx - 90)) * (objectposes[vertindex].x - offset.x))
    sine += 0.001
    vertindex += 1
```

Comment: Unable to debug, because verts and other variables and functions are undefined.  Minor point: say scene.autoscale = False, not scene.camera.autoscale = False.

Comment: Sorry i forgot i made this, but from experimenting, it appears the scene.camera.axis values are sin and cos values

Comment: I just track the camera rotation when the player moves it with the arrow keys